# Convert 2 similar computed properties to use 1 reusable function in Swift?

Tags: swift, cocoa

I have 2 similar computed properties like x & y

```
struct Window {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    var x: String {
        get {
            let x = defaults.string(forKey: "x")
            return x ?? "3"
        }
        set {
            defaults.set(newValue, forKey: "x")
        }
    }

    var y: String {
        get {
            let y = defaults.string(forKey: "y")
            return y ?? "10"
        }
        set {
            defaults.set(newValue, forKey: "y")
        }
    }
}
```

And as x & y are doing the same thing, I want it to make it as a reusable function taking 2 different parameters, the `forKey` name like "x" & "y" & `defaultValue` like "2" or "3" in the above example.

I'm new to Swift & can't seem to figure it out if its possible or too easy. How should I do it?

Comment: Instead of hardcoding those values just use variables which you will update to reflect the latest requirement?

Comment: How do I do that? I'm a Swift noob but I think what you are saying is to pass Parameters but computed properties don't take parameters I think. Do I need to make another struct or class or func? Also, a demo code will be helpful :)

Comment: I would inline the `x`/`y` vars, and write single line getters and setters: `get { defaults.string(forKey: "y") ?? "10" }`

Comment: I would save them both as one object called point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct Window {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    var x: String {
        get {
            return getValue(for:"x", defaultValue: "3")
        }
        set {
            set(value: newValue, for:"x")
        }
    }

    var y: String {
        get {
            return getValue(for:"y", defaultValue: "10")
        }
        set {
            set(value: newValue, for:"y")
        }
    }

    func getValue(for key:String, defaultValue:String) -> String {
        let value = defaults.string(forKey: key)
        return value ?? defaultValue
    }

    func set(value:String, for key:String) {
        defaults.set(value, forKey:key)
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't really help. It's still 1 function call per get/set

Comment: Yes this doesn't help bcz its still the same thing. What I want is 1 function that can be called from 2 places if it exists in Swift. This is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Your properties use custom backing storing. You will have to write something like this. Just because you want something doesn't mean it is possible — or the right thing to do.

Comment: Ohh yeah I'm a Swift noob so that's why I asked if its possible or not. Your new solution is also somewhat similar. I have 5 getters & setters doing the same thing ,i.e, retrieving a String data. Can I use function or class for what I want to do so my code remains short? Or is it bad practice?

Comment: our solutions are not similar: if you would like to change the backing mechanism (lets say to plist instead of user defaults), you would have to touch 10 places for your 5 properties. with my solution just 2, for any number of properties.

Comment: @deadcoder0904 my answer was based on the understanding that you would need to keep changing the key for x and y throughout your program, which is not possible in this approach. However if the keys are static then this is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this approach used in your question and posted answers would not work for multiple objects. What you should do is extend UserDefaults and add a static property nested in a Window struct as follow:

```
extension UserDefaults {
    struct Window { }
}
```

---

```
extension UserDefaults.Window {
    static var x: CGFloat {
        get {
            return CGFloat(UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Window.x") as? Double ?? 2.0) 
        }
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(Double(newValue), forKey: "Window.x") 
        }
    }
    static var y: CGFloat {
        get {
            return CGFloat(UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Window.y") as? Double ?? 3.0)
        }
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(Double(newValue), forKey: "Window.y")
        }
    }
}
```

Playground testing

```
UserDefaults.Window.x       // 2  default value
UserDefaults.Window.x = 10
UserDefaults.Window.x       // 10
```

---

A better approach (as already mentioned by @Sulthan in comments) would be merging x and y properties in a point (CGPoint) property

```
extension UserDefaults.Window {
    static var point: CGPoint {
        get {
            guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "Window.point") else { return CGPoint(x: 2, y: 3) }
            return (NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? NSValue)?.cgPointValue ?? CGPoint(x: 2, y: 3)
        }
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: newValue), forKey: "Window.point")
        }
    }
}
```

Playground testing

```
UserDefaults.Window.point          //   {x 2 y 3}  default value
UserDefaults.Window.point = .zero
UserDefaults.Window.point          //   {x 0 y 0}
```